# How to make Kotlin Library like Java Library?

Tags: java, kotlin, annotation-processing, java-module

I am writing custom `@Builder` annotation processing library (similar to [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) ) with **Java Module** in *Android Studio*. Instead of making a **Java Module** and writing in Java, I want to write it in Kotlin.

Since there is no **Kotlin Module** option in *Android Studio*, I started new a new **Java Module** and wrote in java.

```
@AutoService(Processor.class)
public class BuilderProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    private Filer filer;
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> set, RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {
        for (Element element : roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Builder.class)){
            TypeSpec binder = createClass(element.getSimpleName().toString());
            TypeElement typeElement = (TypeElement) element;
            JavaFile javaFile = JavaFile.builder(getPackage(typeElement.getQualifiedName().toString()), binder).build();
            try {
                javaFile.writeTo(filer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
        Set<String> annotations = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        for (Class<? extends Annotation> annotation : Collections.singleton(Builder.class)) {
            annotations.add(annotation.getCanonicalName());
        }
        return annotations;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnvironment) {
        super.init(processingEnvironment);
        this.filer = processingEnvironment.getFiler();
    }

    private String getPackage(String s){
        return s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('.'));
    }

    private TypeSpec createClass(String className){
        return TypeSpec.classBuilder(className + "Builder")
                .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.FINAL)
                .build();
    }
}
```

The above code works pretty fine and creates a class `UserBuilder.java` if there is an annotation `@Builder` on top of `User` class.

Now I wanted to convert in Kotlin. So, I converted the code into Kotlin

```
@AutoService(Processor::class)
class BuilderProcessor : AbstractProcessor() {

    private var filer: Filer? = null
    override fun process(set: Set<TypeElement>, roundEnvironment: RoundEnvironment): Boolean {
        for (element in roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Builder::class.java)) {
            val binder = createClass(element.simpleName.toString())
            val typeElement = element as TypeElement
            val javaFile = JavaFile.builder(getPackage(typeElement.qualifiedName.toString()), binder).build()
            try {
                javaFile.writeTo(filer!!)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }
        return false
    }

    override fun getSupportedAnnotationTypes(): Set<String> {
        val annotations = LinkedHashSet<String>()
        for (annotation in setOf(Builder::class.java)) {
            annotations.add(annotation.canonicalName)
        }
        return annotations
    }

    @Synchronized
    override fun init(processingEnvironment: ProcessingEnvironment) {
        super.init(processingEnvironment)
        this.filer = processingEnvironment.filer
    }

    private fun getPackage(s: String): String {
        return s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('.'))
    }

    private fun createClass(className: String): TypeSpec {
        return TypeSpec.classBuilder(className + "Builder")
            .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.FINAL)
            .build()
    }
}
```

And also configured the grade with Kotlin

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    api 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
    implementation 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc2'
    implementation project(':builder')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
}

sourceCompatibility = "7"
targetCompatibility = "7"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

But, unfortunately when I build it doesn't work. It builds, but it does not generate `UserBuilder.java` class. Am I doing it wrong or is there any step that I should have done?

There is Kotlin version of **Project Lombok** for a [reference](https://github.com/ThinkingLogic/kotlin-builder-annotation).

Comment: If you'd like to do it properly like _Lombok_, you could have a look into _Kotlin_ compiler plugins. Regarding your question: could you add more information about what's not working and why?

Comment: Sorry, for not giving more information. I just updated. So, basically it builds but it does not generate `UserBuilder.java` class.

Comment: Well, in fact, I have nothing to do with `@Builder` annotation. I just gave it as an example of what I want to do. My intention is just to write a Java library in Kotlin.

Comment: how did you try to build the library?  When you apply the java-library plugin you should get a task under Gradle, in the build folder you can double click on jar to build the library.

Comment: @nPn I don't. I created a new module, included in my app.grade with `kapt project(":buildprocessor")`. That's it when I build the app (Make Project, or just Run) it generates necessary classes when it's written in Java, but doesn't generate when it's Kotlin.